# AudioSessionSetActive and AudioSessionSetProperty is deprecated in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

The following code has been deprecated in iOS 7:

```
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (category), &category);
AudioSessionSetActive (true);
```

Anyone know what the replacement is?

Comment: It's hilarious that this has been marked as a duplicate yet there is no link to the actual answer, and the direct search turns out nothing put exactly this way :(